# javamail: receiving emails from 993 when explictly configured imap and 143? I am using getInstance()

Tags: ssl, jakarta-mail, imap

I am deploying my web project to client environment where we are told not to use SSL and IMAPS. So we configured these properties:

```
mail.recv.protocol=imap
mail.recv.port=143
```

But according to client server log, we are getting this exception:

```
 sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target 
javax.mail.MessagingException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; 
  nested exception is: 
        javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target 
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:695) 
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:345) 
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:226)
```

.....

And provided other information, we are connecting via 993, so we cannot find the certificate `cause jvm asks for it. But we must connect via 143.

With these code we do connection. As you may see, we are not using `getDefaultInstance()` to connect.

```
input = CorreoAction.class.getResourceAsStream("/config/properties/mail.properties"); //we load `prop` from file
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(input);
.....
    prop1 = new Properties(); //we copy prop to prop1 for `store`
        prop1.setProperty("mail.imap.connectiontimeout", "5000");
        prop1.setProperty("mail.imap.timeout", "5000");
        prop1.setProperty("mail.imap.host", prop.getProperty("mail.recv.host"));
        prop1.setProperty("mail.imap.port", prop.getProperty("mail.recv.port"));
        prop1.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.trust", "*");
        prop1.setProperty("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable", "false");

        sesion = Session.getInstance(prop1); //connect with sesion.

        store = sesion.getStore(prop.getProperty("mail.recv.protocol")); //imap, not imaps.
        store.connect(prop.getProperty("mail.recv.host"), prop.getProperty("mail.recv.user"), prop.getProperty("mail.recv.pass"));
```

So, the question is: if we are forcing it to use 143 and imap, why the app connects to 993?

Comment: I suspect you're not getting the properties you think you're getting.  What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?

Comment: Thank you again Bill. Well, I tend to turn it on but in clients' environment we turned it off. Another thing is, although in my code I read prop from `.properties` files inside my WAR, in clients' machine they somehow make it point to another file where they manipulate their own parameters to fit the bank's security requirement. I don't know how they made this work, but as they change parameters in that `.properties` file, different errors appeared so I guess it worked. Of course, they put `imap` instead of `imaps`, and `143` also. May it be the reason?

Comment: Sending the properties correctly is the difference between success and failure.  Without knowing exactly what they set, it's hard to say what they did wrong.